# Align right twentyitem

Tags: tables, align, overleaf

I am using the Twenty Second Resume template (https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/twenty-seconds-resume-slash-cv/mhyfwrmwjkbc).

I have this environment:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

% New environment for the long list
\newenvironment{twenty}{%
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
}

\newcommand{\twentyitem}[4]{%
    \scriptsize{#1}&\quad\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
        \textbf{#2}%
        \quad%
        {\footnotesize#3}\\%
        #4\vspace{\parsep}%
    }\\
}
```

and this code:

```
\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
    \twentyitem{09/2016 - 03/2019}{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}{BBBBBB}{\emph{CCCCCCCCC}\\CCCCCCCC\\ CCCCCCCCCCCCCC}
    \twentyitem{09/2017 - 03/2018}{DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD}{EEEEEEEEEE}{\emph{FFFFFFFFFFFF}\\FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF}
    \twentyitem{09/2013 - 12/2016}{GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG}{HHHHH}{\emph{IIIIIIIIIIIIIII}\\IIIIIIIIIIIIII\\ IIIIIIIIIII}
\end{twenty}
```

This is the result:
[image: result]

How can I align right the BBB EEE and HHH part (the third parameter of `\twentyitem`) ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to replace the `tabular` with a real `itemize`, which has been tailored for your need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{twenty}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=70pt]}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand\twentyitem[4][]{\item[{\scriptsize[#1]}]\textbf{#2}\hfill
  {\footnotesize#3}\\#4}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
    \twentyitem[09/2016 - 03/2019]{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}{BBBBBB}
      {\emph{CCCCCCCCC}\\CCCCCCCC\\ CCCCCCCCCCCCCC}
    \twentyitem[09/2017 - 03/2018]{DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD}{EEEEEEEEEE}
      {\emph{FFFFFFFFFFFF}\\FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF}
    \twentyitem[09/2013 - 12/2016]{GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG}{HHHHH}
      {\emph{IIIIIIIIIIIIIII}\\IIIIIIIIIIIIII\\ IIIIIIIIIII}
\end{twenty}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with `tabularx`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,array}

% New environment for the long list
\newenvironment{twenty}
  {\par\noindent\tabularx{\textwidth}{@{}l@{}>{\raggedright}X@{}r@{}}}
  {\endtabularx}

\newcommand{\twentyitem}[4]{%
  {\scriptsize #1}\hspace*{1em} &
  \textbf{#2}\\
  #4 & {\footnotesize#3} \tabularnewline[\parsep]
}

\begin{document}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
    \twentyitem{09/2016 - 03/2019}{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}{BBBBBB}{\emph{CCCCCCCCC}\\CCCCCCCC\\ CCCCCCCCCCCCCC}
    \twentyitem{09/2017 - 03/2018}{DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD}{EEEEEEEEEE}{\emph{FFFFFFFFFFFF}\\FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF}
    \twentyitem{09/2013 - 12/2016}{GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG}{HHHHH}{\emph{IIIIIIIIIIIIIII}\\IIIIIIIIIIIIII\\ IIIIIIIIIII}
\end{twenty}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unlikely, that doesn't fit in my code and it gives me some errors. I would rather, if possible, use tabular

Comment: @ScTALE Well, using `\parbox[t]{\textwidth}` makes an overfull box for *every* item.